# Creating make rules for dependencies across targets in project's sub-directories

Tags: r, makefile, dependencies, workflow

Source code tree (`R`) for my dissertation research software reflects traditional **research workflow**: "collect data -> prepare data -> analyze data -> collect results -> publish results". I use `make` to establish and maintain the workflow (most of the project's sub-directories contain `Makefile` files).

However, frequently, I need to execute individual parts of my workflow via particular Makefile targets in project's sub-directories (not via top-level `Makefile`). This creates a problem of setting up `Makefile` **rules** to maintain **dependencies** between targets from different parts of the workflow, in other words - between targets in `Makefile` files, located in different sub-directories.

The following represents the **setup** for my dissertation project:

```
+-- diss-floss (Project's root)
|-- import (data collection)
|-- cache (R data objects (), representing different data sources, in sub-directories)
|-+ prepare (data cleaning, transformation, merging and sampling)
  |-- R modules, including 'transform.R'
|-- analysis (data analyses, including exploratory data analysis (EDA))
  |-- R modules, including 'eda.R'
|-+ results (results of the analyses, in sub-directories)
  |-+ eda (*.svg, *.pdf, ...)
  |-- ...
|-- present (auto-generated presentation for defense)
```

**Snippets of targets from some of my `Makefile` files:**

"~/diss-floss/Makefile" (almost full):

```
# Major variable definitions

PROJECT="diss-floss"
HOME_DIR="~/diss-floss"
REPORT={$(PROJECT)-slides}

COLLECTION_DIR=import
PREPARATION_DIR=prepare
ANALYSIS_DIR=analysis
RESULTS_DIR=results
PRESENTATION_DIR=present

RSCRIPT=Rscript

# Targets and rules 

all: rprofile collection preparation analysis results presentation

rprofile:
    R CMD BATCH ./.Rprofile

collection:
    cd $(COLLECTION_DIR) && $(MAKE)

preparation: collection
    cd $(PREPARATION_DIR) && $(MAKE)

analysis: preparation
    cd $(ANALYSIS_DIR) && $(MAKE)

results: analysis
    cd $(RESULTS_DIR) && $(MAKE)

presentation: results
    cd $(PRESENTATION_DIR) && $(MAKE)


## Phony targets and rules (for commands that do not produce files)

#.html
.PHONY: demo clean

# run demo presentation slides
demo: presentation
    # knitr(Markdown) => HTML page
    # HTML5 presentation via RStudio/RPubs or Slidify
    # OR
    # Shiny app

# remove intermediate files
clean:
    rm -f tmp*.bz2 *.Rdata
```

"~/diss-floss/import/Makefile":

```
importFLOSSmole: getFLOSSmoleDataXML.R
    @$(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
...
```

"~/diss-floss/prepare/Makefile":

```
transform: transform.R
    $(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
...
```

"~/diss-floss/analysis/Makefile":

```
eda: eda.R
    @$(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
```

Currently, I am concerned about creating the following dependency:

Data, collected by making a target from `Makefile` in `import`, always needs to be transformed by making corresponding target from `Makefile` in `prepare` before being analyzed via, for example `eda.R`. If I manually run `make` in `import` and then, forgetting about transformation, run `make eda` in `analyze`, things are not going too well. Therefore, my question is:

**How could I use features of the `make` utility (in a simplest way possible) to establish and maintain rules for dependencies between targets from `Makefile` files in different directories?**

Comment: What is the target in `import/Makefile`, and what does it actually produce? What is the target in `prepare/Makefile`, and what does it actually produce? When you `make eda` in `analyze`, what files does it use as input?

Comment: @Beta: Sorry about delay - just got back online. Each target in `import/Makefile`, such as `importFLOSSmole`, produces a set of `.rds` files (I'm considering a change to produce a single `.RData` file) in `cache/<DataSourceName>` sub-directory. Correspondingly, each target in `prepare` either updates existing R data files (targets `transform` and `cleanup`) or produces new R data files (targets `merge` and `sample`) in `cache` sub-directories. `eda` target in `analyze/Makefile` depends on `.rds` files in `cache` sub-directories and produces `.svg` and `.pdf` files in `results/eda` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are my thoughts (with some ideas from @MrFlick's answer - thank you) on adding my research workflow's **data dependencies** to the project's current `make` infrastructure (with snippets of code). I have also tried to reflect the desired workflow by specifying **dependencies** between `make` **targets**.

**import/Makefile:**

```
importFLOSSmole: getFLOSSmoleDataXML.R FLOSSmole.RData
    @$(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
    @touch $@.done

(similar targets for other data sources)
```

**prepare/Makefile:**

```
IMPORT_DIR=../import

prepare: import \
         transform \
         cleanup \
         merge \
         sample

import: $IMPORT_DIR/importFLOSSmole.done # and/or other flag files, as needed

transform: transform.R import
    @$(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
    @touch $@.done

cleanup: cleanup.R transform
    @$(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
    @touch $@.done

merge: merge.R cleanup
    @$(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
    @touch $@.done

sample: sample.R merge
    @$(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
    @touch $@.done
```

**analysis/Makefile:**

```
PREP_DIR=../prepare

analysis: prepare \
          eda \
          efa \
          cfa \
          sem

prepare: $PREP_DIR/transform.done # and/or other flag files, as needed

eda: eda.R prepare
    @$(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
    @touch $@.done

efa: efa.R eda
    @$(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
    @touch $@.done

cfa: cfa.R efa
    @$(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
    @touch $@.done

sem: sem.R cfa
    @$(RSCRIPT) $(R_OPTS) $<
    @touch $@.done
```

The contents of `Makefile` files in directories `results` and `present` are still TBD.

**I would appreciate your thoughts and advice on the above!**

Comment: `make` checks the last modified date on the files to see if they need to be re-built. Since all of your targets are phony (ie, they are not the actual names of files on disc) they will all be re-built every time. This is probably not the behavior you want.

Comment: @MrFlick: Actually, not all my targets are phony. Knowing the basics of `make`, the reason I introduced files `<target>.done` is to use `make`'s standard behavior to control dependencies. It also IMHO helps to maintain dependencies between targets across directories. Am I missing something?

Comment: But you are not listing the .done files as a dependency or as a target so make doesn't know about them. Using done files can be a good strategy, but they should be a part of the dependency chain to be useful in my opinion.

Comment: They are part of the chain - I think you missed references to them: for example, please see `importFLOSSmole.done`, listed as dependency for `import` target, and `transform.done` - for `prepare` target.

Comment: But I don't see a build rule for transform.done. I only see a phony target called transform. Make will not know how to build transform.done if it doesn't exist. Unless that's part of the code you are leaving out or you don't wish to automate the building of those dependencies.

Comment: @MrFlick: I thought that specifying `@touch $@.done` as part of the rule for the target `transform` takes care of letting `make` know about that dependency.

Comment: @MrFlick: Oh, now I see what you mean. I should add an addtional dependency: `transform.done: transform`. This should connect the chain links. Am I correct?

Comment: This has become difficult to address via comments. Make does not look into build recipes to see what's actually made. Everything must be specified on the rule definition line. I suggest you make a small test case for yourself to try out different combinations. You can use `make -n` to see what make would run without actually doing the building.

Comment: @MrFlick: OK, I understand. I will investigate it further. Thank you for your advice on this!

Comment: I would look again at the answer that I originally posted to this question. That's the strategy I recommend. (You may replace file extensions with .done if you like.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your use of makefile right now is that you are only listing the code as dependencies, not the data. That's where a lot of the magic happens. If the "analyze" knew what files it was going to use and could list those as dependencies, it could look back to see how they were made and what dependencies they had. And if an earlier file in the pipeline was updated, then it could run all the necessary steps to bring the file up to date. For example

```
import: rawdata.csv

rawdata.csv:
    scp remoteserver:/rawdata.csv .

transform: tansdata.csv

transdata.csv: gogo.pl rawdata.csv
    perl gogo.pl $< > $@

plot: plot.png

plot.png: plot.R transdata.csv
    Rscript plot.R
```

So if I do a `make import` it will download a new csv file. Then if I run `make plot`, it will try to make `plot.png` but that depends on `transdata.csv` and that depends on `rawdata.csv` and since `rawdata.csv` was updated, it will need to have to update `transdata.csv` and then it will be ready to run the R script. If you don't explicitly set a lot of the file dependencies, you're missing out on a lot of the power of make. But to be fail, it can be tricky sometimes to get all the right dependencies in there (especially if you produce multiple output from one step).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! You're right that as of now my use of `make` is basic (code only), but this is by design. I deliberately delayed creating dependencies, based on data, because earlier I haven't had a clear idea about my workflow and structure of data components. Now, as I have clearer realization about workflow and data, it's time to move on to more advanced use of `make`'s power to automate the workflow for my research. Hence my question. (To be continued)

Comment: Even if `make` has features to maintain dependencies between targets and multiple files (as a whole directory), I'm still leaning toward switching back to use `.RData` files (each per data source) instead of zillion of `.rds` files (each per indicator). This will not only simplify `Makefile` files, but, I hope, allow easier and more natural merging, sampling and visualization of data as well as results of data analysis.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I think that does sound reasonable. And I've found that choosing good file names is very important. If the files at different steps in the pipeline are different just by a prefix or suffix or directory, then it because much easier to write elegant rules. `make` only has one useful form of wildcard/pattern matching and it's pretty limited.

Comment: Would appreciate, if you could share your feedback on my answer.